# slf4j: debug behavior inconsistent?

Tags: log4j, slf4j

I'm using slf4j + log4j with a library of mine.

I am using it in a quick application where I don't really care about configuring the logging... or at least I didn't think I cared.

If I don't configure log4j, I get the standard warning message

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger com.xyz.abcdbabble
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

which is fine.
If I then do

```
logger.debug("Blah blah blah")
```

then the logger doesn't print anything out. Great!

But if I do

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
{
    System.out.println("print some complex stuff:");
    print_some_complex_stuff();
}
```

then the stuff in brackets gets executed. What gives?

I'm looking for a way to determine whether to print out something that should have an equivalent enabling to `logger.debug()`, even if log4j isn't configured in the end application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to figuring out the logic of the log4j default configuration, I would put in a config file (log4j.properties), like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

At least this puts you into control.

Comment: It puts the end user (the person who is *running* java) in control, which is normally the way you want things. Not the person designing the program. In this case, I don't want the normal situation. I have "dumb" users who have no idea & don't care how to setup log4j, and just want to type `java myClass arg0 arg1 arg2`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bundling with log4j then bundle with the "simple" backend from the slf4j distribution.  Then things work as you want them to, and the users cannot tinker.